# fhir java proto not compiling / missing symbols

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, avro

I tried downloading the [google-fhir repo](https://github.com/google/fhir) and running [generate-proto.sh](https://github.com/google/fhir/blob/master/examples/protogen/generate-proto.sh), which generated a bunch of java files in `~/fhir-master/proto/stu3/target/com/google/fhir/stu3/proto` which won't compile. Many objects cannot be resolved: `com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.ReferenceOrBuilder getCoverageOrBuilder();`, `com.google.fhir.stu3.proto.PositiveInt getPriority();`, etc.

At some point, I also generated a bunch of classes (not sure how now, but I think it was with hazel. if you know, please tell me) in `com/google/fhir/stu3/proto`. However when I try to use these classes to extract the schema, none of the symbols can be found: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/fhir/stu3/proto/IdOrBuilder and error: cannot find symbol`, etc.

How do I get all the dependencies to work? How could this possible work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of confusing based on the code and explanation but I will answer your question. If you are compiling your avro schema to java class you should be able to get the schema like this

```
Account.$SCHEMA
```

Now if you are asking how can create and schema from a POJO in java, you can do it like this

```
Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(YourClass.class);
```

About the exception that you are getting, is hard to help you without context or more code to understand what you are trying to do and how.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same errors: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/fhir/stu3/proto/IdOrBuilder and error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(Account.$SCHEMA);
  symbol:   variable $SCHEMA
  location: class Account

Comment: Sorry my question was not well worded, it was more of a complaint. google-fhir has been very difficult to compile and work with. I don't know how or if others find this stuff easy, but it has been very difficult to find a good tutorial that works and explains the environment entirely; I have followed the official and unofficial protocol buffers tutorials and they always break down somewhere with google-fhir. More like a lot of bits and pieces, and its very frustrating. Is this what open source looks like?

Comment: Updated question. Please take a look. Thanks!